# Load Testing a ADF 12c application using JMETER

Tags: jmeter, performance

Has anyone been successful with load testing an application in oracle ADF 12c using JMeter?

We are able to record just fine but when it comes to playback we get all sorts of errors. We have also tried correlation using regex for javax.faces.viewState and afrLoop from blogs but they are all in 11g.

Answer (score 1):

[Official oracle blog](https://blogs.oracle.com/emeapartnerweblogic/working-with-jmeter-for-load-testing-oracle-adf-ui-application-by-ardhendu-samajdwer) links article [Working with JMeter for Load Testing Oracle ADF UI Application](https://ardhendusamajdwer.blogspot.com/2018/04/setup-jmeter-for-oracle-adf-ui.html) by Ardhendu Samajdwer as the resource for JMeter testing of Oracle ADF 12c.

The article describes:

- how to set-up Apache JMeter™ 4.0
- how to create test plan from template Building a Web Test Plan